# Is $\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ a true statement?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I wanted to know whether the following is true or false:

1. $\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$
2. $0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\pi^2)^n}{4^n (2n)!}$

(1.) I know that $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}$. I can write $\ln(\frac{1}{2})=\ln(1+-\frac{1}{2})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(-\frac{1}{2})^n}{n}$, and immediately figure out that the equation in (1) is not true

(2.) This one seems to be oddly specific...I have no idea how to work with the summation so I expanded out some terms. When $n$ is odd the term is negative, and vice versa. The denominator grows way faster than the numerator so as $n \to \infty$ the terms get smaller. I tried some numbers and it seems to be true so far?

Comment: Hint for (1): try substituting $x=1$ into the series for $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Hint for (2): look at the Taylor series for $\cos x$.

Comment: (1) is true. Just because $\ln(1/2)$ can be written in one way does not mean it can’t be written in another. Hint: $\ln(1/2)=-\ln(2)=-\ln(1+1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Recall that $-\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n}$ for all $|x|< 1$. Now if $x=1$, then $\ln(\frac{1}{2})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ (it converges). So yes, it is a true statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n$ converges, you have, by [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem),$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n=\lim_{x\to1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}n.$$But, for each $x\in(-1,1)$,$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}n=-\log(x+1),$$and therefore\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n&=\lim_{x\to1}-\log(x+1)\\&=-\log(2)\\&=\log\left(\frac12\right).\end{align}
2. You have\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-\pi^2)^n}{4^n(2n)!}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(\pi/2)^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\&=\cos\left(\frac\pi2\right)\\&=0.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The first one appears to me to be true:  it's $-\ln2$, since $\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^{n-1}x^n/n$.

The second is $\cos(\pi/2)$.  Remember $\cos x=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nx^{2n}/(2n)!$.